# C# How to deserialize it into variables?

Tags: c#, ajax, json

How to deserialize it into variables? C #. Give an example pls, already the second day and did not get to the library JSON.NET

```
{"messages":[{"text":"TEXT MESSAGE","channel":"main":"from":"USERNAME","fromid":651765,"t":1379970985409,"tc":"f16d7e"}}}
```

So

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string json = @"{""messages"":[{""text"":""TEXT MESSAGE"",""channel"":""main"":""from"":""USERNAME"",""fromid"":651765,""t"":1379970985409,""tc"":""f16d7e""}}} ";


            dynamic stuff = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            string color = stuff.text;
            label1.Text = color;


        }
```

After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: :. Path 'messages[0].channel', line 1, position 52.

Comment: You have errors in your JSON. Check your format here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: A good example of *"why it is a bad idea to form a json manually"*. I don't think any json parser would produce this invalid json.

Answer (score 1):

I think the colon between main and from must be a comma. And the second closing curly should be a squared one.

So your string:

```
@"{""messages"":[{""text"":""TEXT MESSAGE"",""channel"":""main"":""from"":""USERNAME"",""fromid"":651765,""t"":1379970985409,""tc"":""f16d7e""}}} ";
```

should be something like this:

```
@"{""messages"":[{""text"":""TEXT MESSAGE"",""channel"":""main"",""from"":""USERNAME"",""fromid"":651765,""t"":1379970985409,""tc"":""f16d7e""}]} ";
```

Comment: To complete the answer, add also how you would get the *color* correcly,

Comment: @I4V I disagree. Dumping ready-to-paste code here is, especially without explanation, extremely unuseful for OP and future visitors. thorsten mentioned what is wrong about the input, which solves OP's error: _"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered"_.